# TFS: Creating Bugs and Writing the Description Programmatically Space Issue

Tags: c#, tfs, workitem

Hello everyone I'm having an issue writing a description to a bug in TFS.  I can create the bug fine, and I can fill StackRank, Priority, Iteration, etc. just fine.  But when I try to append some lines to a string using StringBuilder and making that the description of the bug, TFS will not recognize any of my AppendLines.  It is as if I am just using Append.

```
        StringBuilder descriptionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.Steps);           
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine("Sales Force Information");          
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.SFTicketNumber);           
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.VersionFoundIn);
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.VersionFixedIn);
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.SFComments);
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.ContactName);
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.SalesforceModified);            
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.LastModifiedBy);
        descriptionBuilder.AppendLine(bugWorkitem.SFProject);

        workItem.Fields["Repro Steps"].Value = descriptionBuilder.ToString();
```

If I debug this code descriptionBuilder.ToString() shows up as having the carriage returns, so I think it has something to do with how TFS formats the description.  How can I get the description to include my carriage returns?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  Even though I am using append line once the string is put into the TFS Bug Description(Or also called Steps) it surrounds the entire string with  <(p)> html which of course puts it all on one line.

To fix this I just added more appends to put <(p)> around each of my desired lines.

Comment: In HTML, New Line characters are not line breaks, you need to use `<br>`